# Uploading file from Google App Engine to Amazon S3 results in exception

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, amazon-s3

i am working on gwt2.4, jre7 and GAE 1.7.3.in development mode my code working properly but when i uploaded my apps on app engine than i am getting following error

```java
 java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:277)
at com.wa.gwtamazon.server.UploadServiceImpl.amazonConfig(UploadServiceImpl.java:124)
at com.wa.gwtamazon.server.UploadServiceImpl.doPost(UploadServiceImpl.java:76)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:100)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)


Nested in java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:124)
at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:86)
at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:31)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:277)
at com.wa.gwtamazon.server.AmazonService.uploadFileToAmazone(AmazonService.java:50)
at com.wa.gwtamazon.server.AmazonService.doPost(AmazonService.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:100)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

i am also find out solution on following link but still it didn't works

(http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8166)

Comment: For your information: Google App Engine only supports JDK 5 & 6. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

//EDIT: He added the following XML to his `appengine-web.xml` to get it work:

```
<system-properties> 
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/> 
    <property name="os.name" value="Linux" /> 
    <property name="os.version" value="6.1" /> 
    <property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM" /> 
    <property name="java.vm.version" value="23.5-b02" /> 
    <property name="user.language" value="en" /> 
    <property name="user.region" value="us" /> 
</system-properties>
```

You can't use the Amazon Libs because of restrictions in the Google App Engine (no Threads, ...).
But there are few solutions that should help you:

[1] http://socialappdev.com/using-amazon-s3-with-google-app-engine-02-2011

[2] https://github.com/handstandtech/s3-simple-appengine

Why don't you use [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/products/cloud-storage) with the [GAE Java SDK](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview)? The GCS API is almost the same as the S3 API.

Comment: but in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8166) they told that problem fixed in app engine 1.7.3 but still i have problem so do you know about that  thing may be some where my mistake in my code or configuration.thanks for your response

Comment: It seems that the bug-report differs to your problem. You are getting a NullPointerException at VersionInfo line 124. I think System.getProperty throws the NullPointerException (os.name or os.version). But in their [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime) they write that System.getProperty is allowed. Try to set the properties on your own as explained [HERE](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6971).

Comment: ya you are right, i also try to put <system-properties>
                                   <property name="os.name" value="..." /></system-properties> this property but i don't know what i have write in value field????? i put different value than upload on app engine still its give me same error as above.

Comment: Debug your application on a local server and look which property throws the exception. Then try different strings that match the property. I think most of the values are optional (but not all of them). If that is not working try to LOG the properties (load them on startup and write them into your log file).

Comment: on local server my apps working properly using filter tag which is given in this [link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8166) but i have to remove filter tag from my web.xml file when i upload my apps on app engine.and error occurred on deployed apps.

Comment: As I mentioned before the link has nothing in common with your problem. The GAE Dev server differs in some parts from the GAE server. Maybe it's working because System.getProperty returns not null on the Dev server. Before you initialize the S3Client, log the output of every System.getProperty in VersionInfoUtils (os.name, os.version, java.vm.name, java.vm.version, ...) and look if it throws an exception. If so, try to set the properties on your own and look if its working correctly.

Comment: ok i will check out this all property one by one.thank you for your response.

Comment: Hey da_re thanks above error gone when i write following code in appengine-web.xml <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    
    <property name="os.name" value="Linux" />
    <property name="os.version" value="6.1" />
    
    <property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM" />
    <property name="java.vm.version" value="23.5-b02" />
    
    <property name="user.language" value="en" />
    <property name="user.region" value="us" />
  </system-properties>

Answer (score 2):

some time app engine didn't get value of os.name,os.version,java.vm.name etc so we have to specify manually in appengine-web.xml file

```
<system-properties>

<property name="os.name" value="Linux" />
<property name="os.version" value="6.1" />

<property name="java.vm.name" value="Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM" />
<property name="java.vm.version" value="23.5-b02" />

<property name="user.language" value="en" />
<property name="user.region" value="us" />
```