# Connection Refused exception while connecting Amazon S3 using HttpUrlConnection

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, amazon-s3, httpurlconnection

I am using gwt 2.5,GAE 1.7.4. I am trying to connection with Amazon S3 and upload file but I am getting Connection Refuse error. and I am not found out any solution from Amazon tutorial. My code is as follow :

```
try{

        URL url = new URL("https://temptxt.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com");

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);

        String userName = "MyAccessKey".trim();
        String password = "MySecretKey".trim();

        String authString = userName + ":" + password;
        String authStringBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(authString.getBytes());
        authStringBase64 = authStringBase64.trim();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/plain");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "AWS" + authStringBase64);

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
        String decodedString;
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Read Data From Response : " + decodedString);
        }
        in.close();

        if (responseCode == 401) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error 401");
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : "+e);
    }
```

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727927/uploading-file-from-google-app-engine-to-amazon-s3-results-in-exception/14728771#14728771) . Read the comments of the accepted answer. Do you get the same exception?

Comment: No, I am getting Connection Refuse exception.

Comment: Add a whitespace to your code: `connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "AWS " + authStringBase64);` -> it's `AWS base64` instead of `AWSbase64`.

Comment: If the whitespace does not work: are you behind a HTTP proxy?